# Indenting for nasm directives and macros

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, code-formatting

In generally accepted nasm syntax, instructions are indented relative to labels, like so:

```
.top:
    dec eax
    jnz .top
```

How about assembly directives and macros, like `%rep`? Should it be like:

```
.top:
    %rep 10
    dec eax
    %endrep
    jnz .top
```

or

```
.top:
%rep 10
    dec eax
%endrep
    jnz .top
```

or perhaps even something else where the directives themselves imply an additional level of indentation - but this would only be applicable to "scoped" directives with open close parts, like `%rep` and `%endrep`, not to standalone or non-nested ones.

```
.top:
    %rep 10
        dec eax
    %endrep
    jnz .top
```

Or something else?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this: it's not asking for an off-site reference.  The appropriate close reason would be "primarily opinion based", as stated in the (don't)-usage guide of the [tag:coding-style] tag.  I chose to answer it anyway because NASM doesn't have any/many well-established style guides that conflict.

Comment: @PeterCordes - the presence of the code-formatting tag seems to indicate that at least some code formatting questions are on topic. I suppose the problematic ones, which would be considered "not constructive" are the opinion based ones like "what brace style to use in C" or naming conventions where there are many options. I'm hoping that in the case of nasm there is one generally accepted or historically used style at least as it relates to directives and hence it is constructive.

Comment: I think [tag:code-formatting] is supposed to be about writing or using *tools* that format code.  Most of the recent questions in that tag are of that nature.

Comment: @PeterCordes - good point, although it could just be because that is the bulk of quesitons that arise today with code formatting: people having trouble formatting their code the way they want it, rather than basic questions about formatting conventions.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I like your suggestion, updated my answer with that (and a justification for *why* it makes good sense.)

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, assembly code was written in a four column layout.  The columns were:

1. label
2. mnemonic
3. operand
4. comment

Traditional assemblers dating back to punched cards recognised the meaning of each word by what column it appeared on.  Modern assemblers use more sophisticated parsers, allowing for assembler programs to have a free form layout.  Nevertheless, it is a good idea to stick with the traditional layout for readability.

As you can see, the second column says “mnemonic.”  This indicates both assembler directives and instructions.  So to answer your question, the directive goes into the same column as other instructions go.  I recommend to highlight bracing like in your `%rep ... %endrep` example by means of blank lines:

```
.top:   %rep 10
        dec eax
        %endrep

        jnz .top
```

Comment: Directives like `%rep` are kind of "meta" things that have an effect on other lines (between rep and endrep), so they very much do *not* act like instructions, or macros that expand to multiple mnemonics.

Comment: @rcgldr Not true.  C code was always indented with tabs (of 8 spaces per tab stop) with 4 spaces for continuation lines in BSD and for assembly programming, historically special tab stops were set.  UNIX still has the **tabs**(1) utility to set up tab stops for various mainframe assemblers.

Comment: @rcgldr The spacing in books is not indicative of what spacing was actually used in practice and was mainly motivated by layouting considerations.  If you look at the C code from that time, it is almost exclusively indented with tabs and tab stops were and still are set to one tab stop every 8 positions.

Comment: @rcgldr For assembly programming, the tab stops varied.  Refer to the manual of tabs(1) for various commonly used tab stops for different (mainframe) assemblers.  The GNU man page doesn't list the exact tab stops, but POSIX and BSD do.

Comment: @fuz - For Microsoft Masm (X86) calling 1st column as 1, then 1, 9, 17, with comments at some "tab" boundary, optionally using tabs == 8 spaces. For IBM 360 family assembler, , then columns 1, 10, 16, 36 or 40, and tabs normally not used since this standard was based on punched cards, even if stored on disk or tape.

Answer (score 2):

I like to **take a cue from C preprocessor style here**, and indent NASM preprocessor directives all the way to the left.  (Or when nesting `%if` and other block-affecting directives, with indents of 2 spaces, so even a nested `%if` still usually starts to the left of the column where instructions mnemonics start).

`%rep` / `%endrep` preprocessor directives affect instruction mnemonics that come between them, so you definitely want them to stand out, not blend and get lost in surrounding instructions.  When you see one, you want to be able to visually spot the other near-instantly, not scan up or down the mnemonics column looking for the first match.  Especially if there's any nesting or other preprocessor trickyness.

Normally you'd only use `%rep` on blocks of multiple instructions or data; otherwise you'd use `time 10 dec eax`.  (Or you're using `%assign` inside `%rep` to create a block like `dec r10d` / `dec r11d` / `dec r12d` / ...)  Therefore real use cases won't be as simple as this example, and the matching `%endrep` / `%rep` will be farther than 2 lines away.

When you have a mix of labels and `%if` / `%rep` directives, it can be harder to see labels.  You don't want `%rep` cluttering the far-left column as well.

Michael Petch's suggestion to further indent the instructions to be repeated is a good one.  They're special anyway, and it's important that readers notice that.  But they are instruction-like in that they expand to a block of instructions, so starting `%rep` in the instruction column makes a lot of sense, and indenting the enclosed block makes it easy to find the start/end of that block.

```
%if USE_SIMPLE_LOOP
.top:
    %rep 10
        imul     ecx, edx
        dec      edx
    %endrep
    sub      eax, 10
    jg      .top
```

Notice that I indented my operands farther, leaving room for mnemonics longer than 3 characters without making the operand column ragged.

I intentionally indented the branch target 1 column less than the other operands, which makes it slightly stand out without being ugly.  Especially when the target is a local label that begins with `.`

But depending on the use-case for `%rep`, it might look better to leave instructions indented to the normal column and use a column between labels and instructions for the `%rep`.

```
%if  USE_SIMPLE_LOOP
.top:                               ; could indent the label by a column or two inside %if
  %rep 10                           ;  unroll 
    imul     ecx, edx
  %endrep
    sub      eax, 10
    jg      .top
%endif
```

---